# NodeJs equvalent implementing simple SOAP

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap

this below code is my PHP solution to use `SOAP` and work fine, now i want to implementing that on `NodeJs`, but i can't and after opening url with `/sendsms` i dont get any result. this soap is for send sms, after get empty result, i dont get any sms from that

```
public static function SendREST($username, $password, $Source, $Destination, $MsgBody, $Encoding)
{
    $URL = "http://URL/sendsms";
    $msg = urlencode(trim($MsgBody));
    $url = $URL . '?username=' . $username . '&password=' . $password . '&source=' . $Source . '&destination=' . $Destination . '&message=' . $msg;

    $headers[] = 'Accept: text/html';
    $headers[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive';
    $headers[] = 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8';
    $process = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    return curl_exec($process);

    try {
        $return = curl_exec($process);
        if ($return) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

My NodeJs solution (data are fake):

```
var soap           = require('soap');
var url = 'http://URL/sendsms';
var args = {username: '5280',password:'3310AZa',source:'08888735280',destination:'97823036569',message:'SHOOOOOOT !!'};

app.get('/sendsms', function (req, res) {
    soap.createClient(url, function (err, client) {
    });
});
```

Comment: Why are you using a SOAP client in node, when in PHP all you're doing is submitting a normal *x-www-form-urlencoded* form request?

Comment: @mscdex this is new project on Nodejs and we must implementing that on Nodejs. could you help me to fixed that?

Comment: Use a module like [`request`](https://github.com/request/request) instead. It allows you to easily submit forms, automatically follow redirects, and other things.

Comment: @mscdex Thanks, but our implementing is SOAP not Restful sir